# How to solve 'invalid binary' issue in appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store

[image]

Appstore keeps complaining about a routing setting of the updated build of my existing app. New build is just an update to the existing one. None of the setting updated and it has nothing to do with routing. But Appstore says it's an 'invalid build' and gives following error

***Invalid routing app setting: To upload a routing app coverage file on App Store Connect, you must define the app binary as a routing app.***

My mapkit capabilities look like this
[image]

Comment: The error says that your bundle includes a routing coverage file but your app doesn't have routing capabilities selected. Remove the routing coverage file from your project.

Comment: @Paulw11, thank you.

Comment: You were able to solve it?, I already deleted the geojson file and it still does not let me send the binary file to review, I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, the problem was that I had a .geoJSON geographical coverage file in the submission page of the AppStore connect, although the app had no routing capability. The solution was to remove this .geoJSON file. However, for this removal to be taken into account by the AppStore connect, I had to

- suppress the build from the submission page
- disconnect from the AppStore connect
- reconnect to the AppStore connect
- re-add the (same) build

Then, resubmitting for validation went smooth.